# On Demand Android User last location and not storing it

Tags: android, gps

Can someone give a suggestion on how I can accomplish this?  Basically my company would like to track all of its drivers route last location without having to store it.  What I means is as follow.

driver A suppose to deliver 5 items to 5 different locations.  So I have android mapped the driving route and off he/she goes.  Location 4 called and said, its address has changed and would like someone to reroute the package to new location.  So main dispatch, will need to check where Driver A is, so that he/she can be contacted and given the information.

I want the dispatch to be able to see driver A route and last location like this.

[image: Location]

How can I accomplish this task without requiring Driver A android device to continuously broadcasting its last location and our server having to store all the devices information in our server.  Basically I'd like to be able to find the last location of Driver A on demand and initiated by our server.

Hope I have explained what I wanted clearly.  Please advise?

Comment: Look under push service, ios has that, So android possibly too.

Comment: Thanks @AlexWien.  That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)  or [android-push-notifications](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications).

Comment: Thanks @AlexWien but that's a third party.  I found GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) and still trying to figure out how to make it works.

Comment: Updated such that other userd find the hint to GCM in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What we decided to do at the end is, to store the historical location directly in our server every 5 minutes and write a code in the app to massage the information according to what we need.  A reverse of what we didn't want to do before but we find no other way to accomplish what we want via google directly.  Unless I'm mistaken.  I'm open to comment.  Many thanks.